# Convert Image from Little to Big Endian

Tags: java, python, tcp, raspberry-pi, endianness

I am trying to transfer an image saved to a raspberry pi from the rpi to an android application to display it. I am treating the raspberry pi as the server and the android app as the client. My server side is implemented using python. I am using pylab to save a figure to the raspberry pi and then later open the image and read the contents as a byte array. This byte array is then passed to the android app, written in java.

I can view the image on the rpi when I open it, but once it is sent to the android, something is happening to it that causes the incorrect number of bytes to be read and the image to be corrupted. I realized that java reads big endian while the raspberry pi byte order is little endian. I am not sure if this is what is causing the problem in transferring the image?

So, I am wondering if there is a way to either encode the byte array as big endian when it is sent from python or a way to decode the byte array as little endian when it is received by java. I tried simply reversing the image byte array in python but that did not work. Any suggestions would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in hardware differences between a Pi and other platforms, but this process can be performed using `ByteBuffer`.

You can get an instance of `ByteBuffer` using `ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray)` or `ByteBuffer.allocate(capacity)`.

You can then set the endian-ness of the buffer using `buffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);` or `buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);`

The data can then be returned with `buffer.get()`.